# Managing resources to run multiple spark applications on the same cluster

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

I am trying to run two spark applications on the same cluster. YARN is the resource manager being used. Both my spark applications are using dynamic allocation.

When I start the first application, it uses up all the resources on the cluster. When  I start the second application, YARN does not allocate it any resources because they are being used by the first application. Once the first application finishes, then and then only does the second application run.

What are the ways to run both the applications simultaneously? I know I can manually assign specific amount of resources to each application before starting them but it doesn't seem like a good solution to me. I am using Hue/Oozie on AWS EMR for running the spark applications. Ideally I would prefer a solution in which I'll be able to assign a maximum percentage of the cluster resources to each application.

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#scheduling-across-applications

Answer (score 0):

You must configure YARN in a fair share scheduling way ([read more here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.4/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/FairScheduler.html)). Generally Hadoop ecosystems are shared systems and based on project or application priority, YARN can be configured so that either all the applications get equal priority or they get a fair share of the containers. If you don't configure anything, it will go to default (FIFO) and be based on the available containers.

Comment: According to Spark's documentation: "Inside a given Spark application (SparkContext instance), multiple parallel jobs can run simultaneously if they were submitted from separate threads.". Configuring YARN in a fair scheduling way won't solve my problem because I have multiple Spark applications with different Spark contexts that I'm trying to run on the same cluster.

Comment: Oh my bad. I just realized that whatever I just talked about was corresponding to configuring Spark in a fair scheduling way and not YARN. I believe you're asking me to configure YARN's fair scheduler, but I don't see how it can help me when I'm using dynamic allocation. It seems easy to use when I use static allocation for Spark.